# Hierachical Regression, accepting/ rejecting hypothesis?!

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, psychology

I have conducted some research and I had three hypotheses. My third hypothesis was 'stress and social support will be predictors of anxiety and depression scores when controlling for age, gender, year of study and degree type.'

My results found that stress and social support were sig predictors for depression, but only stress was a significant predictor for anxiety, social support was not a significant predictor for anxiety.

Therefore, I am confused if I reject my hypothesis or accept? Or will I just have to partially accept it due to the fact the social support was not found to be significant for anxiety, even though everything else was accepted?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some people use the term "hypothesis" rather loosely but its best scientific use is as an outcome expected based on a theory. If the hypothesized outcome did not occur then the data cast doubt on the theory. This appears to be the case here. Of course, it is important to consider whether the failure to confirm a hypothesis is simply due to a lack of power.

On the other hand if your hypotheses are "personal hypotheses" rather than scientific hypotheses, then there is no established way to judge how well you did in coming up with hypotheses nor what you should do if they are falsified.